# Running make under scons in parallel

Tags: gnu-make, scons

I'm working on a (rather horrible) existing build system, where a top-level repository uses SCons and it needs to build dependencies in some sub-repositories that use Make. These builds take quite a bit of time and I'd like to run them with some parallelism.

I realise that SCons has a different implementation of job slots from Make, so I can't hope for the [job server magic](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/jobserver-implementation/) that GNU Make uses. What I'd be perfectly happy with is something where I can say

> Dear SCons: Please run this action (which spawns the Make process) without doing anything else at the same time.

Then I could pass `-j$(nproc)` (or even better the parallelism that was passed to SCons) to the Make process and would know that I won't bring the machine to its knees.

Obviously, running SCons with `-j1` in the first place gets me some of the way there, but I've got some non-trivial work to build with SCons, which *would* benefit from parallelism.

Comment: Is it safe to assume that the rest of the build depends on the products from the sub-repositories built with make?  It seems likely that you can build any other parts of your build at the same time as your make built pieces as long as they are independent...

Comment: Have you tried running SCons from a wrapper makefile that you execute using `make -jN`? You'll need to make sure that you prefix the SCons recipe with `+` so that GNU make exports the job server magic to the SCons process. Then each make process started by SCons should be able to see it. If SCons generates a makefile from its own build information and then calls `make` itself then you'll have to make sure that the sub-`make` recipes in SCons use `$(MAKE)` or the `+` prefix to expose the job server magic to them too.

Comment: @bdbaddog: The problem is that if I run `scons -j10`, I don't want to end up with 10 threads running in Make and another 9 running unrelated SCons actions. I never want to spawn more than 10 jobs in total.

Comment: @StefanBecker: Doesn't that mean that the jobs that scons runs without Make would all have to run serially?

Comment: Yes, but you could utilize/adapt Androids' [makeparallel](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r49/tools/makeparallel/) to eat part of the tokens and pass them to SCons. E.g. your top-level wrapper would be executed with `make -j20`, Scons wrapped with `makeparallel` and `+` prefix, `makeparallel` "eating" 10 tokens and calling `scons -j10`. Then each `$(MAKE)` instance called from SCons would be competing about the remaining 10 tokens, hence you would get in the ideal case 10 SCons + 10 make jobs executed in parallel.

Comment: ... or you could of course add GNU make jobserver client support to SCons. See f.ex. the PR I created for [ninja](https://github.com/ninja-build/ninja/issues/1139).

Comment: @RupertSwarbrick - I understand that. But you've not answered my question. Are the output of all the make builds needed by the rest of the build? (assuming you provide SCons with a list of all (or even specific) outputs from the make and they are needed by your build, then scons won't start any other part of the build until those targets are built by make ..

Comment: @StefanBecker: Hmm, yes. Well, I guess the proper solution is to teach SCons about Make's jobserver, but I was hoping for something easier!

Comment: @bdbaddog: Ok, now I understand. It seems a little fragile: avoiding overloading the machine is now the responsibility of every other target in the SConstruct. Bleurgh. Thanks for the idea, though!

Comment: @RupertSwarbrick - not really what I was saying. I was asking if it was already the case that the products of those make builds were prerequisites of the rest of the build, if so then enforcing that only one of the make builds ran at a time is simple and could be done using SideEffect()